Знаки препинания в БСП: различные действия разных персонажей
Столкнулась с проблемой: какой знак препинания поставить между частями предложения, в которых описываются действия двух персонажей? Не знаю (либо не помню), как это правильно называется, поэтому просто приведу несколько примеров (предложения изменены, но суть такая же, и они не связаны между собой):
Водитель поглядывал на пассажира: тот выглядел отстраненным, словно думал о чем-то своем.
Он схватил блокнот, глядя на друга: тот покачал головой и указал на дверь.
Он бросил недовольный взгляд на Васю: тот вел себя так, будто ничего не произошло.
Он бросил недовольный взгляд на Васю: тот лишь улыбнулся.
Уместно ли здесь двоеточие? Вроде и понимаю, а вроде рука периодически тянется к тире. В одном случае - то, что человек увидел (двоеточие), а во втором - будто два действия идут быстро одно за другим (тире). Подскажите, пожалуйста, чтобы точно понимать, как это работает.

ТЕОРИЯ
Выбор знака в БСП  — это обозначение отношений между частями предложения при отсутствии союзов. В общем случае взаимообусловленные (неоднородные) отношения имеют значения изъяснения, пояснения и причины. Для их обозначения нужен сильный знак (двоеточие или тире), но выбрать знак только по семантике  сложно, так как во всех случаях тире и двоеточие взаимозаменяемы.
При факультативности решений дополнительно используется анализ интонации на стыке предложений. Двоеточие соответствует пояснительной интонации: неполное понижение тона перед значительно увеличенной паузой (интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю). Тире соответствует присоединительной интонации: полное понижение  тона при меньшей паузе.
В целом учитываются все факторы: семантика, структура, контекст. Возможно авторское решение.
РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ
Я считаю возможным такой вариант:
(1) Водитель поглядывал на пассажира: тот выглядел отстраненным, словно думал о чем-то своем.
Действие растянуто по времени, поглядывал — несов. вид. Интонационное предупреждение с остановкой голоса более предпочтительно.
По семантике это пояснение (что видел). Такое же значение в остальных предложениях.
(2) Он схватил блокнот, глядя на друга: тот покачал головой и указал на дверь.
Осложнённая первая часть, собственные знаки, глядя — несов. вид. Лучше двоеточие.
(3) Он бросил недовольный взгляд на Васю — тот вел себя так, будто ничего не произошло.
Тире более предпочтительно: пауза нежелательна, дается описание конкретного момента (бросил — сов. вид). Простая структура первой части.
(4) Он бросил недовольный взгляд на Васю — тот лишь улыбнулся.
Аналогичное решение, тире более предпочтительно.
Примечание. Точка с запятой, как я думаю, не подойдет. Пауза значительная, поэтому взаимообусловленность предложений будет ослаблена.

Водитель поглядывал на пассажира; тот выглядел отстраненным, словно думал о чем-то своем.
Он схватил блокнот, глядя на друга; тот покачал головой и указал на дверь.
Он бросил недовольный взгляд на Васю: тот вел себя так, будто ничего не произошло.
Он бросил недовольный взгляд на Васю; тот лишь улыбнулся.
Только в третьем предложении сохраняем двоеточие - нам явлено "содержание" недовольного взгляда.
В иных случаях - точка с запятой.
